# alert "Invalid jabber ID" when I use sendInvitation method or add withFromJid parameter in new messageBuilder

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp

I just want assign the send user. but when I run my program, I got error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid jabber ID: . or only show Invalid jabber ID.
If no "withFromJid" parameter,the GAE will default application name as the send user, I can not accepted it, so I need assign any user as the send one.

elow is my code:

//code 1.

```
JID jid = new JID("testa@mygmaildomain.com");
JID fromJid = new JID("testb@mygmaildomain.com");
xmppService.sendInvitation(jid,fromJid);
```

//code 2.

```
    JID jid = new JID("testa@mygmaildomain.com");
    JID fromJid = new JID("testb@mygmaildomain.com");
    Message msg = new MessageBuilder()
        .withMessageType(MessageType.NORMAL)
        .withRecipientJids(jid)
        .withFromJid(fromJid)
        .withBody("Hello i'm a fancy GAE app, how are you?")
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, and the cause ended up being a wrong `fromJid` argument, despite the exception reporting on the `jid` argument being invalid. If you have a look at the code in the `XMPPServiceImpl.sendInvitation(JID jabberId, JID fromJid)` method, you will see how this occurs.

Check that both the jid and the fromJid are correct and exist in the XMPP server.